# iMovie still will not download, despite having no other apps, and ~2 GB of storage available?

Tags: ios, applications, imovie, storage

I've been trying to download iMovie for a long time, and I have never had enough space. I have an 8 GB iPhone 5C. I have a project in particular I want to get done, so I deleted all my other apps (other than pre-installed ones, of course) in order to try and download iMovie. According to iTunes, after this, I have 2.04 GB available. I figured this would be enough to download iMovie and get this project over with before deleting it and redownloading all my apps again. And, yet, again I got the dreaded error code declaring that iMovie could not be downloaded at this time and that I didn't have enough storage. I don't know what to do. I know that apps are always more than the number that appears on the App Store page, but even ~2 GB should be enough to download iMovie, right?

How can I download iMovie?

Answer (score 3):

According to the App Store, iMovie would require 641 MB of storage to download on my iPhone 5S (it should be about the same for a 5C), so yes, you have more than enough storage available. I'd try restarting the iPhone, accomplished by holding the power button and home button down together until you see the Apple logo appear. It is completely safe, I do it to my iPhone all the time, it will not delete anything off of your iPhone, nor change any settings, but it may fix little issues like this.

If that doesn't work, try downloading the app through iTunes on your MacBook (or PC) and then sync iMovie to iPhone, that requires less storage, anyway.